# What part of a vim color scheme file controls the dollar signs at the beginning of PHP variables?

Tags: vim, php, colors

I'm trying out a nice scheme called darkspectrum, but it seems to lack support for the dollar signs at the beginning of PHP variables. How do I control them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scheme, add the following lines

```
" PHP $             # #ff0000 is red
hi Operator         guifg=#ff0000     guibg=NONE        gui=NONE      ctermfg=magenta       ctermbg=NONE        cterm=NONE
```